# Starting a Storyboard From A Storyboard

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, storyboard

Is this possible in expression blend?

What i am looking for is to start a storyboard, then at second 2 i would like to start another storyboard.

Why am I looking for this? So I can re-use storyboards and 'pieces' of larger storyboards.  Seems like it would be the most OO I can get from storyboards.

Thanks!

Comment: You can define multiple animation effects in one storyboard. So is there a reason to have multiple storyboards or are you just trying to fire multiple animations fired from one user action ?

Comment: One example I can think of would be: You have a lightning flash on the left side of the screen and one on the right, so you define storyboards called 'flash left' and 'flash right'.  Now, later, you want to make a storyboard called 'doubleflash' which flashes them both at the same time.  Instead of re-defining the flashes, can't you just call flashleft, flashright for simultaneous lightning flashes? Makes sense doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storyboards are not supposed to be OO, they are animation and timeline tools. If you want to create custom and controlled animations, I would advice that you research about the [CompositeTarget.Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering%28VS.95%29.aspx) event and read about animations and easing. You can use [IEasingFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.ieasingfunction%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to select the easing your custom animations would use.

A different option would be to use the [Storyboard.Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event to find out when a storyboard is finished so that you can start another one, but if you decide to go this way you have to be very careful about memory leaks related with event hooks.